# How to access View in xml layout from different Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and android development.

I have a MainActivity.kt file, its associated activitymain.xml file, and a card_layout xml layout file. I would like to be able to access a view from the card_layout.xml in MainActivity.kt, but whenever I try to access the view I get a null pointer exception.

I try to access the view like so in OnCreate() of MainActivity.kt:

```
val v = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rv_relative_layout)
```

and get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: onCreate$lambda-1(...) must not be null
```

Does anyone know why this occurs, and have a way for properly accessing Views from other xml files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this will be specifically useful...New too. I find two ways of referencing views most effective.

1. ViewBinding :

inside

```
 build.gradle (Module:App_Name.app)



android {
...
 buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

in MainActivity:

```
class HistoryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Then reference your veiws by typing binding.camelCaseViewName eg. binding.rvRelativeLayout

2. first create the view variable as a lateinit var before onCreate then instantiate in the place you need it.

im not sure I have understood your question correctly though. My answer is about accessing from .kt not from other xml files.

Answer (score 2):

It will return null because the default `findViewById` method of the current `Activity` is only using the assign `Views` from the `setLayout` method.

You need to inflate another layout so you can access its `Views` from your `Activity` by using [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup))'s `inflate` method.

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null)
val viewFromOther = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.view_from_other)
```